# Algolia Search Facet geolocation

Tags: algolia

We are running a Magento Shop and we want to display products in the customers region. How can we achive this as a facet, like price range? Only that we take the distance as a range.

For a logged in customer we could use the customer-address as a reference point. For guests we could use the IP as a fallback.

Answer (score 2):

If your records are geo-localized (have a `_geoloc: { lat: XXX, lng: YYY}` attribute; yes you can definitely use the geo-search feature to restrict the search to results that are "close to them" (using `aroundRadius` and `aroundLatLngViaIP` for instance).

That being said, maybe you want more control/precision -> so if you are able to filter the results based on a facet value, it would work as well. You'll need to enforce the filter on the underlying `AlgoliaSearchHelper` in the JS code using `addFacetRefinement`.